# Append rows to easy ui

Tags: jquery-easyui

I found this code to append a new row to easyui datagrid, but what about appending some rows more than one? Is there a way to append some rows together at the end of a datagrid?

```
$('#dg').datagrid('appendRow',{
    name: 'new name',
    age: 30,
    note: 'some messages'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add ten rows:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  $('#dg').datagrid('appendRow',{
    name: 'new name',
    age: 30,
    note: 'some messages'
  });
};
```

Comment: I was wondering if there is a function like 'append rowS' instead of using a for loop, thanks for your attention anyway @LuisHP